# How to populate a column in each row with value, which will be combination of two other columns of the same row?

Tags: sql

I have Users table, which has firstName and lastName columns. I want to add a new column userName and populate it with concatenation of firstname and lastname, i.e. John Smith should have smth like john_smith (j_smith) as username

Comment: I might even recommend against doing this, as it represents data duplication.

Comment: What have you tried ? This is really simple; though you may encounter duplicate user names as the table populates.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ALTER TABLE Users
ADD userName AS firstName+'_'+lastName   --John_Smith

ALTER TABLE Users
ADD userName AS LEFT(firstName,1)+'_'+lastName    --J_Smith

Answer (score 1):

SQL have unique feature for this called COMPUTED columns.

Use following code to create your new column. This is for creating computed columns.

```
ALTER TABLE Users
ADD userName AS firstName+'_'+lastName
```

If you want store data physically on your database then you have to use PERSISTED keyword.

```
ALTER TABLE Users
ADD userName AS firstName+'_'+lastName PERSISTED
```

On persisted column you can do indexing also.

Comment: How do you know Yusuf is using SQL Server (that syntax is T-SQL, not "SQL")